# Error while creating spring MockHttpServletResponse, MissingResourceException even after adding javax.servet-api dependency

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am writing test for a servlet filter using spring MockHttpServletResponse and request. I am getting the following error while creating MockHttpServletResponse object.

> Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.servlet.LocalStrings, locale en_US

I tried couple of things suggested on stackoverflow like adding `javax.servlet-api` to pom but even with that its not working.
I tried adding `tomcat server api` in pom, but that is also not working.

My pom file just contains `servlet api`, `jmockit` and `spring-test` dependencies. And I dont have any `message.properties` or any other resource in classpath.

Is there any other dependency that I need to add here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.servlet.LocalStrings, locale es\_ES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561603/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-javax-servle)

Comment: I looked at that link, I have the same dependency in my project but even with that I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need the appropriate version of `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api` in the test classpath.

For Maven, you will need something similar to the following.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```